# find difference between old and new mapping for each clientId

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, sed

I have mappings file like this as shown below:

**new_primary_mapping.txt**

```
{1=[343, 0, 686, 1372, 882, 196], 2=[687, 1, 1373, 883, 197, 736, 1030, 1569], 3=[1374, 2, 884, 737, 198, 1570]}
```

**new_secondary_mapping.txt**

```
{1=[1152, 816, 1488, 336, 1008], 2=[1153, 0, 817, 337, 1489, 1009, 1297], 3=[1, 1154, 1490, 338]}
```

In the above mapping files, each `clientId` has new primary and new secondary mapping. For example: `clientId 1` has `343, 0, 686, 1372, 882, 196` new primary mapping and `1152, 816, 1488, 336, 1008` new secondary mapping. Similarly for other `clientIds` as well. Below is my script which prints arrays for each `clientId`:

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfiles=(new_primary_mapping.txt new_secondary_mapping.txt)

declare -a arr

mappingsByClientID () {
  id=$1 # 1 to 5 
  file=${mapfiles[$2]} # 0 to 1
  arr=($(sed -r "s/.*\b${id}=\[([^]\]+).*/\1/; s/,/ /g" $file))
  echo "${arr[@]}"
}

# assign output of function to an array
# and get mapping for clientId 3
pri=($(mappingsByClientID 3 0))
snd=($(mappingsByClientID 3 1))

# print whole array
echo "whole arr pri: ${pri[@]}"
echo "whole arr snd: ${snd[@]}"
```

Now I have two other files as shown below which has old mapping for same `clientId's`.

**old_primary_mapping.txt**

```
{1=[686, 1372, 882, 196], 2=[883, 197, 736, 1030, 1569], 3=[1374, 2, 884, 737]}
```

**old_secondary_mapping.txt**

```
{1=[1488, 336, 1008], 2=[817, 337, 1489, 1009, 1297], 3=[1490, 338]}
```

**Problem Statement**

Now I need to read all four files and for each `clientId` I need to figure out what is not common (meaning difference) between new and old mapping.

For example: `clientId 1` has `343, 0, 686, 1372, 882, 196` new primary mapping and `1152, 816, 1488, 336, 1008` new secondary mapping.
Also `clientId 1` has `686, 1372, 882, 196` old primary mapping and `1488, 336, 1008` old secondary mapping.

So I will make a pri array which will have this entry: `343 0` and sec array which will have this entry: `1152 816`. Because these are the difference between old and new mapping for each clientId. How can I do that in shell script? Is this possible to do?

Also if there is no difference then just make an empty array and log a message.

**Update:**

For `clientId 1` it should print:

```
pri=(343 0)
snd=(1152 816)
```

For `clientId 2`:

```
pri=(687 1 1373)
snd=(1153 0)
```

For `clientId 3`:

```
pri=(198 1570)
snd=(1 1154)
```

Note: As long as numbers are same then it's a match. Ordering of numbers doesnt matter. So I need to find those numbers which are not common for each clientId.

This is the way I will delete files but when I run it, it gives me error:

```
for dir_name, numbers in (('primary', pri), ('secondary', snd)):
    for number in numbers:
        for filename in glob.glob('/{}/proc_{}_for_*.log'.format(dir_name, number)):
             os.unlink(filename)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
NameError: name 'pri' is not defined
```

Comment: questions: 1) can you consider that the arrays are always growing? This means that in the new arrays there will be more information than in the old ones? 2) are the arrays always generated in the same order old and new?

Comment: size of new array will always be less than old array for each clientId. In the example I have opposite. Just wanted to make it clear in the example so I came up with that. didn't follow your second question?

Comment: example `old_primary` `1=[686, 1372, 882, 196]` and `new_primary` `1=[343, 0, 196, 882, 1372, 686]`

Comment: @Allan it can be in any order. There must be a way to find difference between two arrays I guess?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Why don't you see that as a difference? `new_primary` `1=[343, 0, 686, 1372, 882, 196]` and `old_primary` `1=[686, 1372, 882, 196]`. Here difference is only `343 0` right for primary since other numbers are matching?

Comment: @user1950349, I see it. I considered each pair of structures as `old -- new` at first phase. Post the final expected result/output

Comment: If the actual numbers are the same but their order changes from old to new (e.g. `1=[2,3]` vs `1=[3,2]`) - is that a difference to be reported or not?

Comment: No in that case we should not report the difference. Ordering doesn't matter. As long as number matches then we are good.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I updated the question with expected output.

Comment: @user1950349, is `python` solution acceptable?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest For each `clientId` once I have `pri` and `snd` arrays, I need to delete all those files which have those numbers so I was preferring to have it in shell bcoz I can do everything in one script but with python maybe we can write these numbers in a file for each `clientId` and then have shell script read these two files which has numbers and delete files accordingly. So yeah python solution should be ok as well.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest you still around?

Comment: @user1950349, yes, one more question: are those files `new_primary_mapping.txt` and others static and comes from outside OR you can arrange them manually beforehand?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it comes from outside.. I already have those files before hand generated from other process so I just need to read them and do all the processing..

Comment: @user1950349, done. To get a solution you need to add the tag `python`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170304/discussion-between-user1950349-and-romanperekhrest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Python`** solution:

`diff_mappings.py` script:

```
import sys, re, json

with open(sys.argv[1]) as old_primary, open(sys.argv[2]) as new_primary, \
    open(sys.argv[3]) as old_second, open(sys.argv[4]) as new_second:

    prepare_json = lambda f: json.loads(re.sub(r'([0-9]+)=', '"\\1":', f.read())) 
    old_pr_data = prepare_json(old_primary)
    new_pr_data = prepare_json(new_primary)
    old_snd_data = prepare_json(old_second)
    new_snd_data = prepare_json(new_second)

    for k in sorted(old_pr_data):
        print('ClientId ' + k)
        print('pri=({})'.format(' '.join(map(str, set(old_pr_data[k]) ^ set(new_pr_data[k])))))
        print('snd=({})\n'.format(' '.join(map(str, set(old_snd_data[k]) ^ set(new_snd_data[k])))))
```

*Usage* (the order of input files matters, but the approach can be also rearranged to access the files by names directly within a script):

```
python diff_mappings.py old_primary_mapping.txt new_primary_mapping.txt old_secondary_mapping.txt new_secondary_mapping.txt
```

The output:

```
ClientId 1
pri=(0 343)
snd=(1152 816)

ClientId 2
pri=(1 687 1373)
snd=(0 1153)

ClientId 3
pri=(198 1570)
snd=(1 1154)
```

Comment: aah this is very compact. nice.. also is there any way by which it can print `pri` and `snd` array only for `clientId` passed to this script instead of printing everything? Let's say if I pass `clientId` 3 then it should print `pri` and `snd` array for that clientId only? or maybe I can take one extra paramater and check for k in for loop and print accordingly.

Comment: sure, instead of `for` loop and if key values are known beforehand you may access the wanted key directly e.g. `k = '3'; print('ClientId ' + k); print('pri=({})'.format(' '.join(map(str, set(old_pr_data[k]) ^ set(new_pr_data[k])))))`

Comment: aah I see.. make sense.. let me test it out and see how it looks.. And I was just reading it, I can delete files using python as well so I will modify this script to make that work as well.

Comment: also I was thinking, can we make pri and snd as a proper array? Because I need to iterate them to delete files. I have updated my question in which I have added how I am doing it but with current implementation it doesnt work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

## standard commands

short solution using standard unix command sort and comm

```
new_primary=(343 0 686 1372 882 196)
old_primary=(686 1372 882 196)
comm -23 <( printf "%s\n" "${new_primary[@]}" | sort ) <( printf "%s\n" "${old_primary[@]}" | sort )
```

`comm` takes two files (which must be sorted lexicographically) and produces output with 3 columns with the separator `<tab>`

- first column "only in first file"
- second column "only in second file"
- third column "both"

options `-1` `-2` `-3` are removing corresponding column, so `-23` to keep only in first.

if this operation must be called very often launching many process might be long, in this case it can be done only using bash builtin and functions:

## bash 4

```
arr_to_set() {
    declare -n arr_name=$1
    local set_name=$2 e
    declare -gA "$set_name=()"
    for e in "${arr_name[@]}"; do
        declare -g $set_name[$e]=1
    done
}

comm_set() {
    declare -n set1_=$1 set2_=$2
    declare -gA "comm_only1=()" "comm_only2=()" "comm_both=()"
    for k in "${!set1_[@]}"; do
        if [[ -z ${set2_[$k]} ]]; then
            comm_only1[$k]=1
        else
            comm_both[$k]=1
        fi
    done
    for k in "${!set2_[@]}"; do
        if [[ -z ${set1_[$k]} ]]; then
            comm_only2[$k]=1
        fi
    done
}

new_primary=(343 0 686 1372 882 196)
old_primary=(686 1372 882 196)
arr_to_set new_primary new_primary_set
arr_to_set old_primary old_primary_set
comm_set new_primary_set old_primary_set
typeset -p comm_only1
printf "%8s\n" "${!comm_only1[@]}"
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. how can I have this integrated with my script and also work with old and new secondary mapping?